# iOS Displaying song meta data in multitasking bar and Now Playing lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios, background, media

Is there a way to display song title on the multitasking bar, and multimedia section of the lock screen in a background audio app, like the iPod/Music/Video apps?  So far my app works in background, responds to media playback controls (on the multitasking bar, lock screen, headphones, external accessory, etc.) and handles interruptions, but this is the one thing missing.

Or is this not possible with the current API? (which of so far I have not been able to find any information).

One thing I wanted to check was if Pandora did this, but as I cannot use the app from Australia, I can't verify this. - I seem to recall seeing in a keynote demo that it did, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of iOS 5.0, this is now possible with the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` class.

All you need to know is in the official [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

It is basically a dictionary you populate with the necessary metadata to describe the currently playing media.

Comment: What about next button functionality?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to display information outside of your app about which song is playing while using the backgrounding audio API.  The only action possible is to pause and play your audio.  That is all that Pandora is able to do also.

Comment: Thanks. Well based on that (the one app that if the feature was available, would most likely be the first to use it), I will conclude that it isn't possible (and file a feature request :D)